# How to change the button image of multiple buttons when a button is selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created 12 buttons for months dynamically and i set different image for buttons. All buttons have tags. I access each button with their tag by using switch method. I changed the image of button when selected. But i can't changed the image of other buttons as unselected when a button is selected.

This is my code.

```
//Button Creation in scroll view
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,37,37)];
    [btn setTag:i];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonImageArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(monthBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonArray addObject:btn];
    [btn release];
}

menuScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
menuScrollView.bounces = FALSE;
menuScrollView.delegate = self;
menuButtons = buttonArray;

float totalButtonWidth = 15;

for(int i = 0; i < [menuButtons count]; i++)
{
    UIButton *btn1 = [menuButtons objectAtIndex:i];

    CGRect btnRect = btn1.frame;
    btnRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth;
    [btn1 setFrame:btnRect];
    btn1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [menuScrollView addSubview:btn1];
    totalButtonWidth += btn1.frame.size.width+25;
}

[menuScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(totalButtonWidth, 45)];
[self.view addSubview:menuScrollView];
//Button Action Method
-(IBAction)monthBtnAction:(id)sender {
 NSLog(@"Button Tag is : %i",[sender tag]);

switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d January",[sender tag]);
        flag0 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);
        [self viewWillAppear:NO];
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d Febraury",[sender tag]);
        flag1 = YES;

        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];


        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d March",[sender tag]);
        flag2 = YES;

        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

       break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d April",[sender tag]);
        flag3 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];


        break;
    case 4:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d May",[sender tag]);
        flag4 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];


        break;
    case 5:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d June",[sender tag]);
        flag5 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];


        break;
    case 6:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d July",[sender tag]);
        flag6 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

        break;
    case 7:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d August",[sender tag]);
        flag7 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

        break;
    case 8:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d September",[sender tag]);
        flag8 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

        break;
    case 9:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d October",[sender tag]);
        flag9 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];


        break;
    case 10:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d November",[sender tag]);
        flag10 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

        break;
    case 11:
        NSLog(@"Tag:%d December",[sender tag]);
        flag11 = YES;
        theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonSelectArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        dateValue = [sender tag]+1;
        NSLog(@"dateValue:%d",dateValue);

        [self viewWillAppear:NO];

        break;        
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a class variable of NSButton type and at the end of your IBAction method (after the switch-case), set its value to sender. This will save the tag of button last clicked.

Now in the beginning of IBAction method (before switch), set the image of the button you saved as the unselect image.

```
**.h file**
UIButton* lastClickedButton;

// Your IBAction
-(IBAction)monthBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    [lastClickedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonUnselectArray objectAtIndex:[lastClickedButton tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Your switch statement 
    switch
    { 
      ----
      ----
    }

    lastClickedButton = sender;
}
```

Comment: Its worked for me. One correction in your answer. In .h file its not NSButton its UIButton. Please correct it.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks.I work on OSX, so missed it :). Corrected now.

Comment: Well, this answer helped me as well. Thank you :)